# How to read file input from a text file in pc to arduino

Tags: python, file-io, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

So, basically I have a file on my pc which contains some statements (string). I want to send those strings character by character to arduino uno. fopen() doesn't work in arduino (if that's what i read is correct).
I don't know if serial port will work as taking input from a file on my pc.
Is there a way to send character by character data to arduino?If yess, then please guide me.
If data can be sent through python and/or command prompt(terminal) please tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide code to show what you have done till now and what you need help with. Simply asking and explaining theoretically makes it hard for others to help

Answer (score 0):

There are countless ways to communicate with an Arduino, given you have the respective shields. Wifi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, ...

You can use a USB to Serial converter, connected to the Arduinos Rx/Tx pins. Most if not all Arduinos come with an integrated USB to serial converter onboard. Connect the Arduino to your PC with a USB cable. Make sure you have the drivers for that USB-serial converter installed and you're ready to go.

All you need to know is how to send data from your PC through the virtual COM port of that USB-serial device and how to read that data within your Arduino sketch.

Then you open a file on your computer and send it to the Arduino byte by byte.

There are countless tutorials available. Just search the web for "Arduino serial" and "Python serial" in case you want to do the PC part in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not possible to read a text file from an Arduino sketch (except if it's on an SD card), I found a workaround.

Suppose you want to read (include) a file containing:

A=123; B=546; C=3 and all the data you want.

You have to put a tag in the .ino file (for example // xxxx)

All you have to do is read the file containing the sketch (.ino) with a PHP script and rewrite it line by line, adding the desired text.
As I use PHP to create my data from an SQL database, it is the language that I naturally used.
Hoping it can help..

```
<?php

$FileHandle = fopen('Essai.txt','r');
$i = 0;
// on stocke les lignes avec une date dans un array
// put lines of text file in a array
while ($line = fgets($FileHandle)) {
    $ArLine [$i] = $line;
    echo ('<br>'.$ArLine[$i]);
    $i++;
    
}

$NbEl = count($ArLine);
echo 'Nb lignes dans $ArLine : '.$NbEl.'<br>';
$txt = 'TextToBeInserted';
$myfile = fopen("Essai2.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

for ($i = 0; $i < $NbEl; $i++) { 

    echo ('<br>'.$ArLine[$i]);
    fwrite($myfile, $ArLine[$i]);
    if (strpos($ArLine[$i], 'xxxx') == true) fwrite($myfile, $txt);
}

close($myfile);
```

?>